# Multiple LISTAGG function in one SQL from different table

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I am trying to get data from the different tables using the LISTAGG function in Oracle SQL developer. Able aggregate ID data, but unable to get corresponding ID's value from another table to another column. Here is sample table data and expected outpout.

please help me to build the query.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9IlV.png)

Expected Output:

| UID | U_Name | role_id | role_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 50,60,70 | DEV,TEST,QC |
| 2 | user2 | 60,70 | TEST,QC |
| 3 | user3 | 60,70 | QC |

Comment: Please show you current attempt and describe what was wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

```
select Uid, user_name,
LISTAGG(role_id,',') 
WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY role_id) AS role_id,
LISTAGG(role_name,',') 
WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY role_name) AS role_name from
(select au.Uid,au.user_name,r.role_id, r.role_name from 
Auth_user au join user_role ur on au.Uid = ur.Uid
join role r on ur.Role = r.role_id) FL
GROUP BY FL.Uid
```

Comment: A quick look at the OP's desired output shows that the second LISTAGG shouldn't be ordered by `role_name`. Can you figure out what it should be ordered by?

Comment: Getting below error, while executing
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: I have made a correction can u try now